# Changing textview color in listview item dynamically

Tags: android, sqlite

i m using simple cursor adapter to fetch all records from a view in listview with custom layout. i want to show the priority textview to change color according to text such as red if priority is high,green if medium and yellow if low.is there some way to do it.i m quite new to android

my code for listview

```
myList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myAdapter.open();

    Cursor cursor = myAdapter.fetchAllView();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
String []from=new String[]{ DbAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION,DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,DbAdapter.KEY_TASK_PRIORITY,DbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME,DbAdapter.KEY_TIME,DbAdapter.KEY_DATE };
int[] to=new int[] { R.id.txtdescription,R.id.txtitem,R.id.txtPriority,R.id.txtcategory,R.id.txttimeOne,R.id.txtDateOne}; 
 myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ListItems.this, R.layout.items, cursor,from, to);
myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

listview works fine but how to write a code to change textview color in listview item

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use use your custom cursor adapter, in that you can change things dyanamically

here I am giving an example, in bindView method change the color of text

```
public class MessageAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private Cursor mCursor;
private Context mContext;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;


public MessageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
mContext=context;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView mobileNo=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobileNolistitem);
    mobileNo.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TextMeDBAdapter.KEY_MOBILENO)));

    TextView frequency=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.frequencylistitem);
    frequency.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TextMeDBAdapter.KEY_FREQUENCY)));

    TextView rowid=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowidlistitem);
    rowid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TextMeDBAdapter.KEY_ID)));

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_item,parent,false); 
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: sir i m getting data into listview from SQlite database view and i want to change the priority textiew color through code

Comment: sir i can't understand this concept sorrrry

Comment: Instead of using SimpleCusrsorAdapter use cusom adpater which extends CursorAdapter

Comment: i hv don my work using cursor adapter thank you so much Kapil vats

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using a [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). This will give you much more control over each row.

Comment: sir is there any way to cahnge textview color in listview item according to text

Comment: Yup, with a BaseAdapter you can change what view is displayed & what you do with the views.

Comment: sir from view i means SQlite Database view from which i m getting data into listview

Comment: By View I'm referring to Android Views such as a TextView. Using a BaseAdapter you will be able to set the color of the TextView dynamically.

Comment: is there some code snippet i am really not understanding this concept

Comment: Looks like you accepted the other answer, do you not need the code snippet now?